# Convert drawn line into polyline

Tags: flutter, dart, math, polygon, polyline

Currently I want to program a mobile app in flutter that turns a drawn line into a polyline. However, I'm a newbie in flutter, so I wanted to know if this is even possible. If it's possible how should I proceed?